# How to show Myanmar font from database in webview

Tags: android, webview

I store Myanmar font in database. When I show Myanmar font by webview, They show the followings. How do I change my codes? Please help me.

á€•á€›á€™á€á± (á€•á€›á€™ + á€¡á€á³) = á€¡á‚á€½á€…á€¹á€á€ºá€³á€•á€¹áŠ á€¡á€»á€™á€„á€¹á€·á€†á€¯á€¶á€¸ á€žá€­á€…á€›á€¬á‹

```
These are my codes.
 dstory = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dstory);
 String data=result.getString(3);
 dstory.loadData(data , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Yes, I tried css but don't work.

Comment: Check My answer! and give me an update.

Comment: I write css file in asset folder. In DetailActivity.java  dstory.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", PAGE_HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "null" );

Comment: Can you Update your css?

Comment: My codes doesn't work css file. I don't know what's wrong. In css file,           @font-face {
    font-family: 'ZawgyiOne2008';
    src: url('assets/ZawgyiOne2008.ttf');  
}
body {
 font-family: ZawgyiOne2008;
 font-size: medium;
 color: green;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding Fonts to your Asset folder and add it to your WebView by CSS

You Code Should be loaded from asset directory

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and your CSS should be

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'my_font';
   src: url('my_font.ttf');
}
```

Comment: I write css file in asset folder. In DetailActivity.java write the following. But It doesn't work.  dstory.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", PAGE_HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "null" );

Comment: please update your Question with CSS that your Using!

Comment: Change src:url to this src:url('file:///android_asset/ZawgyiOne2008.ttf') @aungaye

Comment: Css file doen't work. I write in css file as you say. what's wrong. String linkCss = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"file:///android_asset/style.css\"   type=\"text/css\">";
dstory.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", linkCss, "text/html", "UTF-8", "null" );

Comment: Besides css method, Is there anything to show Myanmar font correctly?

Comment: You are adding only the linkCss file where is your Html data? its better to add full html to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

@Muthu Thank u for your advice.Now I got it.

In css file,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ZawgyiOne2008';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/ZawgyiOne2008.ttf');  
}
body{
    font-family: ZawgyiOne2008; width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

In my DetailActivity.java, to link css is used full html.

```
        WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html =
        "<html><head><LINK href=\"file:///android_asset/bootstrap.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></head><body><H1 class='label'>A simple HTML page</H1>" +
        "<input type='text' class='input-large' required='true' id='cname' name='cname'/>" +
        "<input type='text'/>" +        
        "<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></body></html>";
        view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

To show Myanmar Font from database, use string replace.

```
String old="%@";
String newstr=html.replace(old, data);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)! if my answer was helpful accept my answer or upvote them! @aung aye